# Oracle - conditional merge on multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running a merge on a single table with the following query:

```
    MERGE INTO tbl rs
    USING 
    SELECT res.sid, res.eid, res.a, res.b, res.c, res.d, res.e /* ... */
    /* Merge magic here */
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET rs.a = res.a, rs.b = res.b, rs.c = res.c, rs.d = res.d, rs.e = res.e;
```

Now, when one column contains different data than the original the update would be run on all 5 columns in a given row. Is there a way to restrict the update to update only the columns which are different and leave out the columns without differing data?

Comment: Why do you want to omit the columns whose value is equal? For auditing reasons?

Comment: This merge is going to be run often, I want to reduce the number of writes to the absolute minimum.

Comment: Whether you update only one column or 10 columns, oracle always reads and writes whole blocks of data, and save also blocks of data on disk, not indyvidualv bytes, I don't think so that you reduce writes to minimum, but you increase CPU costs because more calculations will be reqired to decide which column should/shouldn't be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but you could restrict the UPDATE to those rows with at least one changed value with a WHERE clause in your UPDATE:

```
MERGE INTO tbl rs
USING 
  (SELECT res.sid, res.eid, res.a, res.b, res.c, res.d, res.e /* ... */ )
ON ( /* Merge magic here */ )
WHEN MATCHED THEN    
UPDATE SET 
      rs.a = res.a, 
      rs.b = res.b, 
      rs.c = res.c, 
      rs.d = res.d, 
      rs.e = res.e
WHERE rs.a <> res.a 
   OR rs.b <> res.b 
   OR rs.c <> res.c 
   OR rs.d <> res.d 
   OR rs.e <> res.e;
```

(depending on your data / application logic, you might want to add extra checking for NULL values).